# Why do I need a function for this Visual Basic code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, function, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to figure out the functions for an application that you order donuts and coffee through.  There is no box to input quantities.  The type of doughnuts are selected using radio buttons grouped in combo boxes as is the type of coffee. The user ordering does not input any information.  That application calculates according to the selected radio buttons.  There is also a 3% sales tax.

The donuts are as follows:
Glazed are $0.65, Sugar $0.65, Chocolate are $0.85, and Filled are $1.00.

The coffee costs:
Regular is $1.00 and cappuccino is $2.50.

How do I write a function for each one?  I would think I would just write one function that calculates the donut, coffee and sales tax.  I am not sure what I am supposed to include if there is only one possible choice for each case.  I thought that I could just write a bunch of constants since nothing changed and do an If statement but the assignment is asking for functions.

This is what I have so far for the doughnuts.

```
Private Function GetDonutPrice(ByVal strDonut As String) As Double
     Dim dblDonutPrice As Double
     'Calculates and returns the price of donuts 
     If strDonut = "G" Or strDonut = "S" Then
        dblDonutPrice = 0.65 
     ElseIf strDonut = "C" Then
        dblDonutPrice = 0.85
     Else
        strDonut = "F"
        dblDonutPrice = 1.0 
     End If

     Return dblDonutPrice 
 End Function
```

And then for the btnCalc_Click I coded this:

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
     'Displays donut and cappucino subtotal, taxes and price 
     Dim strDonutPrice As String
     Dim dblDonutPrice As Double
     If radGlazed.Checked Then
        strDonutPrice = "G" 
     ElseIf radSugar.Checked Then
        strDonutPrice = "S" 
     ElseIf radChoc.Checked Then
        strDonutPrice = "C"
     ElseIf radFilled.Checked strDonutPrice = "F"
     End If
    ' get the donut price ' 
    dblDonutPrice = GetDonutPrice(strDonutPrice) 
 End Sub 

 And I get an error in dblDonutPrice = GetDonutPrice(strDonutPrice)
```

Comment: `Why do I need a function` because the assignment calls for it and it is important to know how to do this.

Comment: It sounds like you need a function that receives the type and quantity of doughnuts and does the math and returns the cost. And the same for the coffee.  So you will have three functions total.  The coffee, the doughnuts, and the main one that take the input of what is order and how many, calls the other functions, adds it up, and then does the sales tax.

Comment: For future reference,  questions here should be phrased in a way to ask for help on problems with code.  Show the attempt you have made at something and the community can help get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: There is no quantity input for this assignment and you can only choose one type of doughnut because of the radio buttons.  That's why I thought there should just be one function that adds everything up together instead of separate functions.

This is what I have so far:

Comment: This is how I coded it so far:


Private Function GetDonutPrice(ByVal strDonut As String) As Double

        Dim dblDonutPrice As Double

        ' calculates and returns the price of donuts '
        If strDonut = "G" Or strDonut = "S" Then
            dblDonutPrice = 0.65
        ElseIf strDonut = "C" Then
            dblDonutPrice = 0.85
        Else strDonut = "F"
            dblDonutPrice = 1.0
        End If

        Return dblDonutPrice

    End Function

(How do you make the code box show up?)

Comment: And then for the btnCalc_Click I coded this:
    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        ' displays donut and cappucino subtotal, taxes and price '
Dim strDonutPrice As String
Dim dblDonutPrice As Double
If radGlazed.Checked Then
strDonutPrice = "G"
ElseIf radSugar.Checked Then
strDonutPrice = "S"
ElseIf radChoc.Checked Then
strDonutPrice = "C"
ElseIf radFilled.Checked
strDonutPrice = "F"
End If
' get the donut price '
dblDonutPrice = GetDonutPrice(strDonutPrice)
    End Sub   And I get an error in dblDonutPrice = GetDonutPrice(strDonutPrice)

Comment: @Marlinda I added your code the best I could to your question.  When adding information to your question, you should edit the question instead of adding the info in comments.  This will bring the question back to the top of the main stack overflow page and it it is easier to read.  I have edited your post and added your code the best I could as the code came out as one long line from the comment..

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks for the help.

Comment: Also I noticed you asked how to get the code box to show up. It does not in the comments. These are only text.  When you put code in the question area, select that text and hit the {} icon at the top of the question box.  If this question does not get any more attention, you should close it and open a different question highlighting the objective and what you have so far.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a function that receives the type and quantity of doughnuts and does the math and returns the cost. And the same for the coffee. So you will have three functions total. The coffee, the doughnuts, and the main one that take the input of what is order and how many, calls the other functions, adds it up, and then does the sales tax

Something like this maybe.

```
Private Sub cmdAddItUp_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdAddItUp.Click
    Dim iQuantity1 as integer
    Dim dDoughnutCost as double

    'Get the data to send to doughnuts
    iQuantity1 = val(TextBox1.Text)
    iQuantity2 = val(TextBox2.Text)
    etc.

    'Get the doughnuts cost
    dDoughnutCost = Doughtnuts(iQuantity1, iQuantity2, iQuantity3)

    'Do the same for the coffee
    dCoffeeCost = Coffees(iQuantity1, iQuantity2, iQuantity3)

    'Add it up
    dSubTotal = dDoughnutCost  + dCoffeeCost 

    'Calculate tax
    dTotal = Tax(dSubTotal)

    'Now you have the total, do something with it. Display it maybe!

End Sub

Private Function Doughtnuts(iQuantity1 As Integer, iQuantity2 As Integer, iQuantity3 As Integer) As Double
    'Do the math
End Function

Private Function Coffees(iQuantity1 As Integer, iQuantity2 As Integer, iQuantity3 As Integer) As Double
    'Do the math
End Function

Private Function Tax(dSubtotal As Double) As Double
    'Calculate tax
End Function
```

Hope that helps get you started.  Good luck with your schooling.

Answer (score 1):

I made some assumptions on your UI. Rather than placing the items as radio buttons in a `ComboBox`, I placed all of the doughnuts and coffees into a respective `GroupBox`. The concepts of this answer will still apply, however you'll just have to be mindful that this is not directly drop-in and go.

Here's the way I laid out the UI:

[image: UI Layout]

I have placed the `RadioButton`s for the items inside a `FlowLayoutPanel` inside of a `GroupBox`. I also placed labels into a TableLayoutPanel to provide the total amounts.

The most important part is how I named the `RadioButton` controls for the items being listed. In the code behind file I used the names of the `RadioButton` controls to check which Item was being modified. I could have populated the `RadioButton` controls at run time to ensure that everything lined up, but that was more work and it's not difficult to do if you use `GetType(MyEnum).GetNames()` in the `Me.Load` event of the form to create new `RadioButtons` with the correct name, text, and adding the proper event handlers to the radio buttons.

If you'd like to see how this works, add a new form to your Project and call it DoughnutsAndCoffee. Here is the designer file and the Code behind:

Code Behind:

```
Public Class DoughnutsAndCoffee
    Private SelectedItems As New List(Of Items)
    Public Event ItemsChanged()

    Public Sub UpdateTotal() Handles Me.ItemsChanged
        Dim subTotal As Decimal = 0D

        For Each item As Items In SelectedItems
            subTotal += Prices.GetPrice(item)
        Next

        Dim TaxTotal As Decimal = subTotal * Prices.Tax_Rate
        Dim total As Decimal = subTotal + TaxTotal

        Me.SubTotal_Label.Invoke(Sub() Me.SubTotal_Label.Text = subTotal.ToString("C2"))
        Me.Tax_Label.Invoke(Sub() Me.Tax_Label.Text = TaxTotal.ToString("C2"))
        Me.Total_Label.Invoke(Sub() Me.Total_Label.Text = total.ToString("C2"))

    End Sub


    Private Sub RadioButton_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Cappuccino_RadioButton.CheckedChanged, Chocolate_RadioButton.CheckedChanged, Filled_RadioButton.CheckedChanged, Glazed_RadioButton.CheckedChanged, Regular_RadioButton.CheckedChanged, Sugar_RadioButton.CheckedChanged
        Dim senderRB As RadioButton = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)
        Dim selectedItem As String = (From item As String In GetType(Items).GetEnumNames Where senderRB.Name.Contains(item) Select item).FirstOrDefault

        If selectedItem <> String.Empty Then
            Dim Item As Items = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(Items), selectedItem), Items)
            If senderRB.Checked Then
                Me.SelectedItems.Add(Item)
                RaiseEvent ItemsChanged()
            Else
                If Me.SelectedItems.Contains(Item) Then
                    Me.SelectedItems.Remove(Item)
                    RaiseEvent ItemsChanged()
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DoughnutsAndCoffee_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        RaiseEvent ItemsChanged()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Structure Prices
    Public Const Tax_Rate As Decimal = 0.03D
    Public Const Glazed As Decimal = 0.65D
    Public Const Sugar As Decimal = 0.65D
    Public Const Chocolate As Decimal = 0.85D
    Public Const Filled As Decimal = 1D
    Public Const Regular As Decimal = 1D
    Public Const Cappuccino As Decimal = 2.5D

    Public Shared Function GetPrice(item As Items) As Decimal
        Dim itemStr As String = [Enum].GetName(GetType(Items), item)
        Return GetType(Prices).GetField(itemStr).GetValue(Nothing)
    End Function

End Structure

Public Enum Items
    Glazed
    Sugar
    Chocolate
    Filled
    Regular
    Cappuccino
End Enum
```

Designer File:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class DoughnutsAndCoffee
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.Glazed_RadioButton = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.Sugar_RadioButton = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.Chocolate_RadioButton = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.Filled_RadioButton = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.Regular_RadioButton = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.Cappuccino_RadioButton = New System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton()
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel()
        Me.Total_Label = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Label5 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Tax_Label = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Label3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.SubTotal_Label = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.FlowLayoutPanel2 = New System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel()
        Me.FlowLayoutPanel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel()
        Me.Coffee_GroupBox = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
        Me.Doughnuts_GroupBox = New System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox()
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout()
        Me.FlowLayoutPanel2.SuspendLayout()
        Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout()
        Me.Coffee_GroupBox.SuspendLayout()
        Me.Doughnuts_GroupBox.SuspendLayout()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Glazed_RadioButton
        '
        Me.Glazed_RadioButton.AutoSize = True
        Me.Glazed_RadioButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 3)
        Me.Glazed_RadioButton.Name = "Glazed_RadioButton"
        Me.Glazed_RadioButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(58, 17)
        Me.Glazed_RadioButton.TabIndex = 9
        Me.Glazed_RadioButton.Text = "Glazed"
        Me.Glazed_RadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Sugar_RadioButton
        '
        Me.Sugar_RadioButton.AutoSize = True
        Me.Sugar_RadioButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 26)
        Me.Sugar_RadioButton.Name = "Sugar_RadioButton"
        Me.Sugar_RadioButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(53, 17)
        Me.Sugar_RadioButton.TabIndex = 10
        Me.Sugar_RadioButton.Text = "Sugar"
        Me.Sugar_RadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Chocolate_RadioButton
        '
        Me.Chocolate_RadioButton.AutoSize = True
        Me.Chocolate_RadioButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 49)
        Me.Chocolate_RadioButton.Name = "Chocolate_RadioButton"
        Me.Chocolate_RadioButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(73, 17)
        Me.Chocolate_RadioButton.TabIndex = 11
        Me.Chocolate_RadioButton.Text = "Chocolate"
        Me.Chocolate_RadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Filled_RadioButton
        '
        Me.Filled_RadioButton.AutoSize = True
        Me.Filled_RadioButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 72)
        Me.Filled_RadioButton.Name = "Filled_RadioButton"
        Me.Filled_RadioButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(49, 17)
        Me.Filled_RadioButton.TabIndex = 12
        Me.Filled_RadioButton.Text = "Filled"
        Me.Filled_RadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Regular_RadioButton
        '
        Me.Regular_RadioButton.AutoSize = True
        Me.Regular_RadioButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 3)
        Me.Regular_RadioButton.Name = "Regular_RadioButton"
        Me.Regular_RadioButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(62, 17)
        Me.Regular_RadioButton.TabIndex = 13
        Me.Regular_RadioButton.Text = "Regular"
        Me.Regular_RadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Cappuccino_RadioButton
        '
        Me.Cappuccino_RadioButton.AutoSize = True
        Me.Cappuccino_RadioButton.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(3, 26)
        Me.Cappuccino_RadioButton.Name = "Cappuccino_RadioButton"
        Me.Cappuccino_RadioButton.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(82, 17)
        Me.Cappuccino_RadioButton.TabIndex = 14
        Me.Cappuccino_RadioButton.Text = "Cappuccino"
        Me.Cappuccino_RadioButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'TableLayoutPanel1
        '
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Anchor = CType((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right), System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = True
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50.0!))
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50.0!))
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.Total_Label, 1, 2)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.Label5, 0, 2)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.Tax_Label, 1, 1)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.Label3, 0, 1)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.SubTotal_Label, 1, 0)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Me.Label1, 0, 0)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(67, 133)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Name = "TableLayoutPanel1"
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 3
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333!))
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333!))
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333!))
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(140, 57)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 9
        '
        'Total_Label
        '
        Me.Total_Label.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left
        Me.Total_Label.AutoSize = True
        Me.Total_Label.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(80, 41)
        Me.Total_Label.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10, 3, 10, 3)
        Me.Total_Label.Name = "Total_Label"
        Me.Total_Label.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 13)
        Me.Total_Label.TabIndex = 5
        Me.Total_Label.Text = "Label6"
        '
        'Label5
        '
        Me.Label5.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left
        Me.Label5.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label5.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 41)
        Me.Label5.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10, 3, 10, 3)
        Me.Label5.Name = "Label5"
        Me.Label5.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(31, 13)
        Me.Label5.TabIndex = 4
        Me.Label5.Text = "Total"
        '
        'Tax_Label
        '
        Me.Tax_Label.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left
        Me.Tax_Label.AutoSize = True
        Me.Tax_Label.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(80, 22)
        Me.Tax_Label.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10, 3, 10, 3)
        Me.Tax_Label.Name = "Tax_Label"
        Me.Tax_Label.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 13)
        Me.Tax_Label.TabIndex = 3
        Me.Tax_Label.Text = "Label4"
        '
        'Label3
        '
        Me.Label3.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left
        Me.Label3.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 22)
        Me.Label3.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10, 3, 10, 3)
        Me.Label3.Name = "Label3"
        Me.Label3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(25, 13)
        Me.Label3.TabIndex = 2
        Me.Label3.Text = "Tax"
        '
        'SubTotal_Label
        '
        Me.SubTotal_Label.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left
        Me.SubTotal_Label.AutoSize = True
        Me.SubTotal_Label.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(80, 3)
        Me.SubTotal_Label.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10, 3, 10, 3)
        Me.SubTotal_Label.Name = "SubTotal_Label"
        Me.SubTotal_Label.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(39, 13)
        Me.SubTotal_Label.TabIndex = 1
        Me.SubTotal_Label.Text = "Label2"
        '
        'Label1
        '
        Me.Label1.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left
        Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 3)
        Me.Label1.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(10, 3, 10, 3)
        Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
        Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 13)
        Me.Label1.TabIndex = 0
        Me.Label1.Text = "SubTotal"%0
```